# Flutter application crashes when when executed in debug mode in android 5.1.1 but works fine if we execute in release mode

Tags: android-studio, flutter

While running Fluter application in debug mode it crashes in Android 5.1.1 but  if i execute the same in release mode it works fine.So when i executed application in debug mode Its like this

```
in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       4.7s  
Resolving dependencies...                                   23.4s  
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...                           4.6s  
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk (25.7MB).  
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                 219.9s  
I/FlutterActivityDelegate(14495): onResume setting current activity to this
F/libc    (14495): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x80 in tid 14548 (gpu_thread)  
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***  
Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/A6020a46/A6020a46:5.1.1/LMY47V    /A6020a46_S105_161124_ROW:user/release-keys'  
Revision: '0'  
ABI: 'arm64'  
pid: 14495, tid: 14548, name: gpu_thread  >>> com.ashish.creatingui <<<  
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x80
x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000007f8b57d890  x3   0000000000000000
x4   0000000000000000  x5   00000055c8cacd48  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
x8   0000007f8c853700  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000000
x12  0000007f8ac04938  x13  0000000000000003  x14  0000000000810001  x15  0000000000000000
x16  0000000000000000  x17  0000000000000000  x18  00000000ffffffff  x19  0000007f8c853bd8
x20  0000007f8c85378a  x21  0000007f8c856888  x22  0000007f8c854540  x23  0000000000000002
x24  0000007f8c853770  x25  0000007f8c853ba0  x26  0000007f8ac04000  x27  0000007f8c853540
x28  00000000fffffffe  x29  0000007f8c853320  x30  0000007f8ac49718
sp   0000007f8c853320  pc   0000007f8ac49718  pstate 0000000020000000  
backtrace:  
#00 pc 00000000001fc718  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so  
#01 pc 00000000001e6634  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so  
#02 pc 000000000023763c  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so  
#03 pc 000000000021c2f8  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so  
#04 pc 0000000000246ed4  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so  
#05 pc 000000000024c6d4  /system/vendor/lib64/libsc-a3xx.so   (__compile_shader_source+1972)  
#06 pc 00000000000b1d44  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so   (core_glCompileShader+268)  
#07 pc 000000000007b3c0  /system/vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glCompileShader+32)  
#08 pc 000000000034371c  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64  /libflutter.so
#09 pc 000000000034293c  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64  /libflutter.so  
#10 pc 00000000003421e0  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#11 pc 0000000000341e20  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#12 pc 00000000003393cc  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#13 pc 00000000003310cc  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#14 pc 0000000000333ad4  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#15 pc 00000000002ad8f4  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#16 pc 00000000003001ac  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#17 pc 00000000002ffe80  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#18 pc 00000000002f9918  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#19 pc 00000000002c0c80  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#20 pc 00000000002a7d7c  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#21 pc 00000000002a7988  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#22 pc 00000000002a7f98  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#23 pc 00000000002bf308  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#24 pc 00000000001a01a0  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#25 pc 000000000019d724  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#26 pc 000000000019d6c8  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#27 pc 000000000019e6d0  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#28 pc 000000000019e994  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#29 pc 000000000019edf8  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#30 pc 000000000019eb00  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#31 pc 000000000019e81c  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#32 pc 0000000000192784  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#33 pc 000000000016b71c  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#34 pc 000000000016f960  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#35 pc 0000000000019020  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+516)  
#36 pc 0000000000019268  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+76)  
#37 pc 000000000000bd58  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+84)  
#38 pc 000000000016f904  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#39 pc 000000000016b7f8  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#40 pc 000000000016da9c  /mnt/asec/com.ashish.creatingui-2/lib/arm64/libflutter.so  
#41 pc 0000000000018f70  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)  
#42 pc 00000000000150f0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)  
Lost connection to device.  
Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_05  
Error initializing DevFS: TimeoutException: Request to Dart VM Service timed out: _createDevFS({fsName: creating_ui})
```

This is the console output after fluter run
The app crashes on Lost Connection to device
But works fine when executed in release mode

Comment: What does "crashes" mean exactly? You could try `flutter run --release` from the console and post the output.

Comment: I added the debug output

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues I think there were similar issues reported recently. Also ensure you have the latest Flutter version `flutter channel dev` `flutter doctor`.

Comment: yes i checked it, and it works fine in debug mode in android 8

Comment: If you didn't find one, I'd suggest you create one.

Comment: i did find the issue and it is persisting in many devices, thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please post a link here?

Comment: yeah they are tracking this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15228

Answer (score 0):

Given that the issue was resolved per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15228), this crash shouldn't be recurring in the [current version of Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases).